# Android: Issue with regex matcher.find() always returns false

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to create a payment form like the below sample:

[image]

When user fills his credit card number, it should display the card logo on the left hand side in the edit text. Below is my code with which I started:

```
String pattern = "^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\\d{3})\\d{11})$";
final Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(pattern);

edtCardNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean mFormatting; // this is a flag which prevents the
                                        // stack overflow.
        private int mAfter;

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAfter = after;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e("CCTest", "after text changed");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!mFormatting) {
                Log.e("CCTest", "after text changed if");
                mFormatting = true;
                // using US formatting...
                if (mAfter != 0) { // in case back space ain't clicked...
                    Log.e("CCTest",
                            "after text changed mAfter != 0 "
                                    + s.toString());
                    Matcher matcher = pattern1.matcher(s.toString());
                    Log.e("CCTest",
                            "after text changed mAfter != 0 "
                                    + matcher.find());
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        Log.e("CCTest", "matcher find");
                        if (s.charAt(0) == '4') {
                            Log.e("CCTest", "matcher find if");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "VISA",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                mFormatting = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But, [matcher.find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) always returns false hence toast message is not showing up. I am not getting where did I made mistake.

Comment: Could you include, in your question, what `Log.e("CCTest","after text changed mAfter != 0 " + s.toString());` outputs?

Comment: That regex matches credit card numbers *only* if they are complete, and if they don't contain anything besides the number (i. e. no spaces etc.). Is that what you're testing it against?

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is a problem with your regex pattern.

Try your regex defination [here](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/)

also this a good site for generating regex